# Hive CLI with Tez failed due to localization of Resources

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

when launching Hive CLI it failed with below Log

`2023-07-08 10:00:46,822 INFO  [main] tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:localizeResource(1159)) - Localizing resource because it does not exist: file:/home/hadoop/tez/tez.0.10 to dest: hdfs://HostName:9000/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/9cfed3fe-ac8a-411f-a54e-900ede1b7304-resources/tez.0.10 2023-07-08 10:00:49,788 INFO  [main] tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:localizeResource(1182)) - Looks like another thread or process is writing the same file 2023-07-08 10:00:49,792 INFO  [main] tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:checkOrWaitForTheFile(1211)) - Waiting for the file hdfs://Hostname:9000/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/9cfed3fe-ac8a-411f-a54e-900ede1b7304-resources/tez.0.10 (5 attempts, with 5000ms interval) 2023-07-08 10:01:14,829 ERROR [main] tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:localizeResource(1190)) - Could not find the jar that was being uploaded Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Previous writer likely failed to write hdfs://Hostname:9000/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/9cfed3fe-ac8a-411f-a54e-900ede1b7304-resources/tez.0.10. Failing because I am unlikely to write too. at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:683) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:591) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:747) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318) at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Previous writer likely failed to write hdfs://Hostname:9000/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/9cfed3fe-ac8a-411f-a54e-900ede1b7304-resources/tez.0.10. Failing because I am unlikely to write too. at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.localizeResource(DagUtils.java:1191) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.addTempResources(DagUtils.java:1042) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.localizeTempFilesFromConf(DagUtils.java:931) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.ensureLocalResources(TezSessionState.java:610) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.openInternal(TezSessionState.java:287) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.beginOpen(TezSessionState.java:256) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:680) ... 9 more` 
Any Help please
I tried to copy all tez jars to that location but it didn't work

I tried to copy all tez jars to that location but it didn't work

Comment: Did you check this folders exists on hdfs **/tmp/hive/hadoop/** and your user does have permission to write this folder

Comment: yes, but still not working

Comment: check the resource path specified in the Tez configuration (tez.lib.uris property in tez-site.xml). Ensure that the resource exists at the specified location and that the path is accurate.

Comment: Yeah, its already considered and configured